# How would you pass whole HTML code of the current screen to ASP.NET controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web-development-server

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to pass the whole HTML code of the current screen to ASP.NET Controller action

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And if someone says "yes, there is", then what's your next question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, and since I wanted to try SO `run snippets` :), this *trivial* sample may get you started.

```js
function foo() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("result");
  var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  ele.innerText = html;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">Try Me</button>
<p>
  <textarea id="result" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
</p>
```

- Now you have your "HTML source" text, well, except for the top level `html` element.
- You can do whatever you want to `POST` it somewhere, however you choose, which I'll leave up to you to handle :)

Fun times ~